# path planning for turtlebot using moveit planner

Tags: navigation, moveit, turtlebot2, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I use moveit planner as global path planner for the turtlebot navigation? More precision: ros automatically use Djiasktra for path planning when navigating a turtlebot. I want ros to use one of the planner available in moveit or OMPL for path planning. How can I do this? I use ros Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343703/path-planning-for-turtlebot-using-moveit-planner/) by [kiko453](https://answers.ros.org/users/45196/kiko453/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To extend the above answer:

You can definitely use OMPL inside of navigation. All the planners and algorithms are pluginlib plugins. You can create an OMPL plugin to replace the global planner that uses Dij. / A*. There are a few out there already if you search through GitHub.

Ex.
https://github.com/ykarmesh/RRT-Plugin

https://github.com/procopiostein/ompl_planner_base

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0